# Ajuda com alteraçao de sistema com menor trabalho

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, lógica

Tenho uma tabela de produtos:

```
CREATE TABLE produtos (
  idProduto int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tipo enum('m','p') NOT NULL,
  modelo varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  bandejas enum('1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  peso int(4) DEFAULT '0',
  prensagem int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  precoUnitario int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  comprimento int(3) NOT NULL,
  largura int(3) NOT NULL,
  cabo varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ligacao enum('m','b') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'b',
  potencia int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  consumo int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  corrente int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  disjuntor int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  descricao text NOT NULL,
  estoque int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  bloqueado char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (idProduto)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

E a Classes Produtos

```
<?php
 Class Produtos {

  private $idProduto; 
  private $tipo;  
  private $modelo;   
  private $bandejas;    
  private $peso;  
  private $prensagem;  
  private $precoUnitario;  
  private $comprimento;  
  private $largura;
  private $cabo;
  private $ligacao;  
  private $potencia;
  private $consumo;
  private $corrente;
  private $disjuntor;
  private $descricao;
  private $estoque;
  private $bloqueado;  

  public function __construct (
      $_tipo,  
      $_modelo,   
      $_bandejas,    
      $_peso,  
      $_prensagem,
      $_precoUnitario,  
      $_comprimento,  
      $_largura,
      $_cabo,
      $_ligacao,  
      $_potencia,
      $_consumo,
      $_corrente,
      $_disjuntor,
      $_descricao,
      $_estoque,
      $_bloqueado
                     ) {
      $this->tipo =  $_tipo;
      $this->modelo = $_modelo;
      $this->bandejas = $_bandejas;
      $this->peso = $_peso;
      $this->prensagem = $_prensagem;
      $this->precoUnitario = $_precoUnitario;
      $this->comprimento = $_comprimento;
      $this->largura = $_largura;
      $this->cabo = $_cabo;
      $this->ligacao = $_ligacao;
      $this->potencia = $_potencia;
      $this->consumo = $_consumo;
      $this->corrente = $_corrente; 
      $this->disjuntor = $_disjuntor;
      $this->descricao = $_descricao;
      $this->estoque = $_estoque;
      $this->bloqueado = $_bloqueado;
  }

  ////////////////////// SET'ERS  //////////////////  

  public function setIdProduto ($_idProduto) {
      $this->idProduto = $_idProduto;
  }

  public function getIdProduto(){
      return $this->idProduto;
  }

  public function getTipo () {
      return $this->tipo;
  }

  public function getModelo () {
      return $this->modelo;
  }

  public function getBandejas(){
      return $this->bandejas;
  }

  public function getPeso(){
      return $this->peso;
  } 

  public function getPrensagem(){
      return $this->prensagem;
  } 

  public function getPrecoUnitario(){
      return $this->precoUnitario;
  }  

  public function getComprimento(){
      return $this->comprimento;
  }

  public function getLargura(){
      return $this->largura;
  }

  public function getCabo(){
      return $this->cabo;
  }

  public function getLigacao(){
      return $this->ligacao;
  }

  public function getPotencia(){
      return $this->potencia;
  }

  public function getConsumo(){
      return $this->consumo;
  }

  public function getCorrente(){
      return $this->corrente;
  }

  public function getDisjuntor(){
      return $this->disjuntor;
  }

  public function getDescricao(){
      return $this->descricao;
  }

  public function getEstoque(){
      return $this->estoque;
  }

  public function getBloqueado(){
      return $this->bloqueado;
  }
}
```

À principio, seria para cadastrar apenas máquinas que têm todos aqueles atributos.

Porém, no final, o cliente resolveu vender também na loja, acessórios destas máquinas dos mais diversos tipo e que logicamente não tem vários dos atributos que as máquinas possuem.
Por exemplo podemos citar chapa de metal usada para a confecção das máquinas quem não atributos tipo corrente elétrica, potência, etc...
Mas têm atributos do tipo peso, preço, etc...

Alguma solução em OO que me ajude a não ter um trabalho de remodelagem geral do sistema a fim de contornar esse problema?

Comment: No caso, a solução mesmo é repensar o uso de OO em PHP, que é a causa de todos estes problemas. Note que você está buscando por OO, mas fazendo uma estrutura típica de procedural "à moda antiga", que é criar chamadas com 2793 parâmetros posicionais todos "hardcoded" na classe. Pra trabalhar em OO, você precisa ter visão geral do sistema, e já prever o máximo de versatilidade ANTES de começar a escrever o código. O procedural sofre menos com isso. Notar que não é uma crítica a OO, e sim ao mau uso "institucionalizado" do paradigma, principalmente em PHP.

Comment: Imagine se cada vez que tiver um dado variável novo, você precisar editar a classe inteira para ajustar? Aí alguma outra empresa (ou um setor diferente) se interessa no sistema, e os produtos deles são um pouco diferentes, começa a ter que manter duas versões do código, e daí pra frente só piora a situação. Talvez seja o caso de abstrair estas coisas enquanto é cedo. Antes um pouco mais de trabalho agora, do que um sistema insustentável no futuro.

Comment: Entendi. Só que apenas agora o cliente resolveu falar sobre isso e sempre omitindo a informação quando perguntado. Acho que a saída será mesmo remodelar! aff.